# How can I accessing Yoroi keys from a script?

Tags: yoroi

Is it possible to access yoroi private keys from the outside? For example, to write a script that does something with them?

Answer (score 4):

Yoroi doesn't need to be involved. You can access your keys using the [cardano-wallet](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-wallet) suite of tools. You just need your seed phrase.

Yoroi and other wallets are just interfaces to the blockchain. The private keys on the chain are the same. Using the command line tools developed my IOG is basically what the wallets are doing behind the scenes.

Comment: Just to clarify, Yoroi does not use cardano-wallet, since it's a frontend JS app it relies on a WASM compilation of cardano-serialization-lib (rust).

Comment: The point is that the wallet software (e.g., Yoroi) is just a window into the blockchain. You can use the cardano-wallet to make scripts to interface with your ADA just like Yoroi or Daedalus (just need the seed phrase). If they are using Rust, JS, etc. to write their scripts then the cardano-serialization-lib may be useful.

Comment: @nalyd88 can you add those informations to your answer? Then I will accept it. I think it is important to have answers as complete as possible.